# How to use merge function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table query is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
    D#      NUMBER(5)   NOT NULL, /* Department number      */
    DName       VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Department name        */
    Manager#    CHAR(5)     NOT NULL, /* Department manager number  */
    MSDate      DATE,             /* Manager start date         */
    CONSTRAINT Department_PK PRIMARY KEY(D#),
    CONSTRAINT Department_CK UNIQUE(DName)
);
INSERT INTO Department VALUES (1, 'SALES', '00110', TO_DATE('02/01/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO Department VALUES (2, 'ACCOUNTING', '00120', TO_DATE('30/10/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO Department VALUES (3, 'GAMES', '00150', TO_DATE('01/03/2008', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO Department VALUES (4, 'HUMAN RESOURCES', '00200', TO_DATE('02/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO Department VALUES (5, 'SPORTS', '00250', TO_DATE('10/05/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

I' m going to implement sql query like the department “SPORTS” will be merged into the department “GAMES”. The manager of the department “GAMES” is still the manager of that department. The employees that worked in the department “SPORTS” stay in the same locations.

```
MERGE INTO department d
USING (
  SELECT Manager#,MSDate
  FROM department d
ON (d.D# = 'GAMES')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET d.Manager# = d.Manager#
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  ...
```

Somehow I had try to use this query to try out but no luck it no working.

Comment: MySQL does not support the `MERGE` statement

Comment: So i only can use Update statement?

Comment: Good point. I've deleted my comment since it's redundant given yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql Does not support `MERGE`

Have a look at [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> If you specify `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY`, MySQL
>   performs an `UPDATE` of the old row.

Comment: `UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET D#=3 WHERE D#=5;
UPDATE DEPTLOCATION D#=3 WHERE D#=5;
DELETE FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE D#=5;
UPDATE PROJECT D#=3 WHERE D#=5;
DELETE FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE D#=5;`

This query had done what i need.
But is there any other way to update the data based on the primary key? The primary key is D# for all the table i'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Merge command not exist on MySql, but you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(col_a, col_b) values ('valueA', 'valueB')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE col_a = 'valueD', col_b = 'ValueE';
```