# SQL Insert if record doesn't exist and update if does exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a zip code table in my database with tax rates, there has been an update to the tax rate table, I need to update all of the zip codes that are already in the database but then I need to add the missing ones.

The update statement is easy:

```
update TaxRate 
set Percentage = 0.055 
where zip = 54986
```

Is there an easy if/else way to add the ones that don't exist? Fairly new to SQL and I have been searching, but can't seem to find a direct answer.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What you are looking is MERGE statement, but marc_s is right, specify the database you are using because depending on this you may not have this statement. For example, for MySQL it seems there is no MERGE, but there is a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631215/how-to-use-merge-function-in-mysql

Comment: So use MERGE statement this way : MERGE TaxRate 
USING (VALUES (0.055, 54986)) AS T(PC, Z)
   ON Z = zip
WHEN  MATCHED 
   THEN UPDATE 
        SET Percentage = PC
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
   THEN INSERT (Percentage, zip)
        VALUES (PC, Z);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upsert (update or insert) in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010511/how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-in-sql-server-2005)